# How to make `SingleChildScrollView` scroll to the last item fetched from `StreamBuilder`?

Tags: flutter, stream

I use a stream builder to fetch my list of messages from the remote database.

Q1) When `hasData`, I'd like the `SingleChildScrollView`to scroll down to the last message I am supposed to display in the `build`, so that the user sees the last message.

How to do that?

Q2) How to `setState((){})` the number of items fetched from the `StreamBuild`?

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        key: _streamBuilderKey,
        stream: ClassifiedAdMessage.getAdMessagesStream(adId: widget.adId),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const CircularProgressIndicatorWithOptions();
            default:
              if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                return const Center(child: Text("No message so far"));
              }

              final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                final map = doc.data();
                return ClassifiedAdMessage.fromMap(map);
              });

              // blah blah

              }

              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(),
                body: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // blah blah
                  ])
                )
              )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally mange to do it.

The key point is to add a callback function to the post frame binder: this event is triggered once the build is performed.
Therefore I take this opportunity —as the content is already set— to jump to the end.

Here is the code:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      scrollToBottom();
    });
  }

  void scrollToBottom() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200)).then((_) {
      if (!_scrollController.hasClients) return;
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is using the `ScrollController` in your `SingleChildScrollView`. When you successfully fetched your data from the server you can use the controller to scroll to the bottom of your scroll view.

For example:

```
scrollController.jumpTo(scrollController.position.minScrollExtent)
```

You could also use `animateTo` instead of `jumpTo`. I recommend the [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) to get more information.